# zabbix can't connect to local MySQL server

Tags: zabbix

When I start zabbix server ,the log show below:

```
# tail 300f /tmp/zabbix_server.log
[Z3001] connection to database 'zabbix' failed: [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/usr/local/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock'
```

my mysql is working and mysql's acount(zabbix) is working;

```
  [root@localhost data]# ps aux |grep mysql
    root      49035  0.0  0.0 113264  1616 pts/2    S    17:00   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql
    mysql     49170  0.0  5.5 1274804 215428 pts/2  Sl   17:00   0:00 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log --pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
    root      49628  0.0  0.0 112660   972 pts/2    S+   17:22   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql

[root@localhost data]# /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u zabbix -p123456
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 4
Server version: 5.7.20 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| zabbix             |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

the sock is here:

```
[root@localhost data]# cd /var/lib/mysql/
[root@localhost mysql]# ll
total 188504
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql     4096 Jan 24 12:30 mysql
srwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql        0 Jan 24 17:00 mysql.sock
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql        6 Jan 24 17:00 mysql.sock.lock
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql     8192 Jan 24 12:30 performance_schema
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql    12288 Jan 24 15:12 zabbix
[root@localhost mysql]#
```

my zabbix_server.conf

```
LogFile=/tmp/zabbix_server.log  
DBName=zabbix                  
DBUser=zabbix                    
DBPassword=123456
```

what something wrong,please help me.

thank you so much at first

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your DB socket is `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`.
So you need to configure zabbix_server.conf for that:

```
DBSocket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Doc: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/appendix/config/zabbix_server

Comment: I try it,and restart the zabbix server ,but the problem is going on

Comment: Maybe SELinux blocks Zabbix connection to the socket.

Comment: # grep SELINUX=disabled /etc/selinux/config  show  SELINUX=disabled

Comment: Do you have the same error message after setting the mysql.sock path in the zabbix server config file ?

Answer (score 0):

Install like this

```
useradd zabbix
yum install net-snmp-devel libxml2-devel libcurl-devel
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/zabbix-3.4.6/ --enable-server --enable-agent --with-mysql --with-net-snmp --with-libcurl --with-libxml2
make 
make install
cp /home/zabbix/zabbix-3.4.6/misc/init.d/fedora/core/zabbix_server /etc/init.d/
```

mysql add account:

```
create database zabbix character set utf8;
grant all on zabbix.* to zabbix@localhost identified by '123456';
flush privileges;
use zabbix;
source /home/zabbix/zabbix-3.4.6/database/mysql/schema.sql
source /home/zabbix/zabbix-3.4.6/database/mysql/images.sql;
source /home/zabbix/zabbix-3.4.6/database/mysql/data.sql;
exit;
```

Comment: The problem is not the installation, it won't help him.

Answer (score 0):

Just restart the server where Zabbix is running.